# Laravel composer absolute path error in VB

Tags: php, laravel-4, ubuntu-12.04, virtualbox, composer-php

I run local virtual box development server with ubuntu 12.04. To access files I use virtual box shared folders which are mounted into ubuntu at /media/Sites. This dir I use as DocumentRoot for apache.

When I try to run `composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist` I get error:

```
    [InvalidArgumentException]
$from (/media/Sites/test.dev/laravel/vendor/bin/boris) and $to () must be absolute paths.
```

I assume problem is because dir /media/Sites is outside of ubuntu in windows 8.1. I also tried to create new laravel project in some linux dir and it worked without any error.

What would be the best fix for this? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure you have all of the requirements installed:

```
$ apt-get install git php5 php5-curl php5-cli php5-mcrypt php5-json
```

then

```
$ wget https://github.com/laravel/laravel/archive/master.zip
$ unzip master.zip project
$ cd project
$ composer install --verbose
```

to see a stack trace of the error, then post it here for more help.

Answer (score 1):

there is some bug in the `boris` package, were it tries to create a symlink to another directory. the solution to this is to manually create the missing file `vendor/bin/boris` with this content:

```
../d11wtq/boris/bin/boris
```

then run `composer update` again and it should work. (in our case we had also some additional problem with unaccessible files created by composer - the files exist in host but are not accessible in guest - `vagrant reload` helps in this case)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same happen to me. Solved it by installing php5-readline.

```
sudo apt-get install php5-readline
```